Use second partition in yocto scarthgap (worked on honnister)
I am in the process of updating our embedded deployment from Honnister to Scarthgap.
In our custom layer, we have the definition of several partition using a wks file defined as such:
part /boot --source bootimg-partition --ondisk mmcblk1 --fstype=vfat --label boot_A --active --align 4096 --size 20
part / --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk1 --fstype=ext4 --label root_A --align 4096
part --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk1 --fstype=ext4 --label root_B --align 4096
part /media --source rootfs --rootfs-dir=${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/media --size 5G --ondisk mmcblk1 --fstype=ext4 --label data --align 4096
part swap --ondisk mmcblk1 --size 44 --label swap --fstype=swap --size=2048M --overhead-factor 1

This file is named my_image.wks.
Using this, I was able in Honnister to add files to the persistent partition /media with this in my recipes like this:
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/media/data
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/usb_eth_mac_addr ${D}/media/data/usb_eth_mac_addr
}
FILES:${PN} += "/media/data/*

However, when I do that in Scarthgap, I do have a QA error:
ERROR: usb-gadget-ethernet-1.1-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: usb-gadget-ethernet installs files in /media, but it is expected to be empty [empty-dirs]

Could someone point me towards the correction I should do?
Thanks
